# UserForm: Regarding Coding and Usage

Tags: vba, excel

Once again, I'll preface my question with the fact that I have no experience in a programming language. However, I've got a UserForm and I'm almost done coding it. Now I just need to finish coding the "OK" button. I'm just not sure how to finish after typing "End With" and "'Clear the form."

My goal is to have the form automatically close out after pressing the "OK" button and enter the user's information into the referenced cells. I have 2 questions as shown below:

First Question: The information the UserForm enters starts on S5 and continues through AB5. I am setting up a macro to have the user click the company name and the UserForm will subsequently pop up. My question is, how will the UserForm be programmed to tab down to the next row?

Second Question: I do not have any IF variables in this form. Exactly how should I be coding area below the "'Clear the form" statement to both submit the information and close out the UserForm for the next entry.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control
RowCount = Worksheets("February Renewals").Range("S5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("February Renewals").Range("S5")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.ComboBoxStatus.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.ComboBoxRemarketed.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier2.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional2.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.ComboBoxLost.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtAdditionalNotes.Value
    End With
    'Clear the form
End Sub
```

I know this is a very long and basic question, so THANK YOU to anyone who is able to answer it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear a Textbox or ComboBox, you can simply use the `.Value` property. For example

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
ComboBox1.Value = ""
```

However if you combobox's style is `fmStyleDropDownList`, then you will have to use the `.ListIndex` property. For example

```
ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically what I should be using in this case would be: End With
'Cleartheform                                                       ComboBoxStatus.Value=""                                             txtAdditionalComments.Text=""                       
End Sub

Comment: before `end sub`, you will set all of them one by one to `""` for example `Me.txtAdditionalNotes=""`

Comment: Sorry, excuse my bad spacing. Thanks again Siddharth Rout!!